# Branching decision tree exit node and visitation duration classfication

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata

I have a dataset where every record in each data cluster corresponds to a step in a branched tree (from an IVR system). I am still learning some of the more machine learning concepts of data science and was wondering for pure detection of exit nodes and detecting time in system, would a flat file analysis be a better option, or is there a better approach that would be faster considering I am dealing with a large (for me) dataset of 2-4 Mil records?  I apologize if this is asked and answered, as I am definitely in a don't know what I don't know scenario here, and would appreciate any help.  I cannot post any of the dataset as it is sensitive info.